# 1 liner RegEx to find next available number

Tags: .net, regex

I have to find the first available number from a string collection

I have a for each loop but that takes for every to complete because it's within a workflow. Workflow lets me use Regex but has to be one liner. I am trying to find next available number from this collection. So in this example, it would be 73.  (If RegEx is not my option then I may have to go with Javascript)

'^(.*?)\d*$'

I would expect 73 from the collection below

1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91;92;1,001;1,002;1,003;1,004;1,005;1,006;1,007;1,008;1,009;1,010;1,011;1,012;1,013;1,014;1,015;1,016;1,017;1,018;1,019;1,020;1,021;1,022;1,023;1,024;1,025;1,026;1,027;1,028;

Comment: Your input has no `73`. A regex is meant to extract text from a longer text.

Comment: Regex is good at *text* patterns, not at comparing numerical values. And as for finding something that doesn't exist, that will never work. Go with javascript!

Comment: I mean RegEx should give me next available number from the collection which is 73. Hope it makes sense. Basically, i need first available number from a collection that not in collection.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: Thank you so much for confirming. Should I keep this post or delete? Sorry didn't know Regex would not be an option.

Comment: When you delete it, I think you will also erase the downvote ;-). You will never get useful answers (other than my comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a javascript to handle this since RegEx is not an option

https://jsfiddle.net/8w7opd6a/1/

```
//var str = "3; -1; 0; 5";
var str = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91;92;1001;1002;1003;1004;1005;1006;1007;73;";
function getMissingNumber(str){
  var arr = str.split(/\;/);
  var missingNum = [];
  for(var i=Math.min(...arr); i<Math.max(...arr); i++){
     if(arr.indexOf(i.toString()) === -1){
       missingNum.push(i);
       if(i){
       alert(i);return; }
     }
  }
  return missingNum;
}
console.log(getMissingNumber(str));
//alert(getMissingNumber(str));
```